# Handling Datetime datatype between javascript and WebApi 2

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I would like to know whether the following is the right method to handle datetime data type in WebApi 2, Javascript and database.

**DateTime from Javascript to WebApi:**

```
var date = new Date();
var datestring = date.toISOString();
//Send datestring to WebApi
```

**DateTime from WebApi to Javascript:**

```
//on getting datetime value from `http.get` call 
var dateFromServer = new Date(dateFromServer);
```

**WebApi:**

> Incoming date

- do nothing simply store the `datestring` returned in database column with datatype `datetime`

> Getting date from database and Returning date to client:

- no datetime manipulation (simply return as per WebApi Json serializer ex: 2015-10-23T18:30:00). Client would automatically convert the UTC datetime to local datetime

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes if you don't want to handle any information about user Timezone etc... this is an acceptable way. 
Just make sure that any time you want a date produced from the server for a comparison or something else to use the c# **DateTime.UtcNow** 
method. 
I think Having a "Global UTC Convention" its a quite safe and good solution but it has some limits.

For example if you want to Alert all of your users located in different timezones at 09:00 am (on each user's country) then its impossible to know when its "09:00" for each one.

One way to solve this(and it's the one i prefer), is to store manually each user's timezone info separately on the database, and every time you want to make a comparison simply convert the time.

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(time, this.userTimezone);
```

Alternatively if you want to store all timezone information on the server you can :

Send  your date from javascript to the server using the following format :
**"2014-02-01T09:28:56.321-10:00"** ISO 8601 also supports time zones by replacing the Z with + or – value for the timezone offset.

Declare your WEB API 2 Date types with the **"DateTimeOffset"** type.

Finally store your dates within the database using the **"datetimeoffset"** type.

This way any time on the server or the database you have all the information about the user's time and timezone.

You will find [this article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jan/06/JavaScript-JSON-Date-Parsing-and-real-Dates) useful